# openlayers WKT readFeatures()

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I would like to read multiple features with `ol.format.WKT`.
In [the documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WKT-WKT.html), it says that the function `readFeatures` takes an array as parameter. I tried the following:

```
let wkt = new ol.format.WKT;
wkt.readFeatures(["POINT(-378147.31208516686 599021.3516006605)", "POINT(-378300.01500700554 599159.7386235767)"]);
```

But I get an error :

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected `` at position 0 in ``
    at Tu (ol.js:659)
    at Ku.k.Gd (ol.js:655)
    at Ku.k.Ng (ol.js:655)
    at Ku.k.Qa (ol.js:562)
    at <anonymous>:1:5
```

Has anyone any clue ? I tried searching on the internet but no exemples are available for this specific method, and there are none either in the documentation...

**EDIT**
The function doesn't takes an Array as parameter but a string or an Object (if I red well). What are the syntaxes to use those inputs ? I had no success so far with GEOMETRYCOLLECTION string (see below).

Answer (score 4):

The doc is a bit misleading, as it means you can read a geometry collection or multi points. It does not mean you can read several distinct wkt in a single read. Moreover it says that the output is an array, not the input.

You can check the [tests](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/test/spec/ol/format/wkt.test.js) to get working examples (it is always a good resource to check when the doc doesn't suffice).

```js
wkt = 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1 2),POINT(3 4))';
features = format.readFeatures(wkt);

wkt = 'MULTIPOINT((10 40),(40 30),(20 20),(30 10))';
geom = format.readGeometry(wkt);
```

So an option would be to loop through your inputs and add the features to the vector layer

Comment: Ow yes lmy bad for the array input i'm still new to those docs. Thanks for the tests link but I tried their way with the GEOMETRYCOLLECTION. I just copy pasted the lines and all I get is a 1 entry array with type GeometryCollection as output...